# How to get the token returned from Azure AD B2C in ASP Core 2.0?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I created a default .NET Core 2.0 MVC Web app with User Account Authentican using Azure B2C. I have been able to successfully log in with my B2C Policy.

I wish to get the user's Access token which will be forwarded on to another api.
I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926661/6569899) but the access_token being brought back in the 2nd step is null event though the id_token is not.

I tried changing the ResponseType option for my OpenIdConnection by adding 'token' to  get "id_token code token" (like shown [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gianlucb/2017/10/04/access-an-azure-ad-secured-api-with-asp-net-core-2-0/)) and I get an error

> Message contains error: 'invalid_request', error_description:
>   'AADB2C90055: The scope 'openid profile' provided in request must
>   specify a resource, such as 'https://example.com/calendar.read'.

I only get the error when the ResponseType has 'token' in it.

How do I fix this error? Do I need to set the Resource or maybe change the scope? Am I going about getting the access_token the right way?

**More Information:**
I created a default .NET Core app with User Account Authentication with Azure. I have been modifying the AzureAdB2cAuthenticationBuilderExtension.cs that is auto-generated.

I modified the Configure function:

```cs
public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
{
    options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
    options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}/{_azureOptions.Domain}/{_azureOptions.SignUpSignInPolicyId}/v2.0";
    options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
    options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;

    // Added 'token' here so I can retrieve the access token
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name" };

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
        OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure,

        //Added this so I can store the access_token in the cache
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,

    };
}
```

Then I added the below function so I can store and later retrieve the access token from the TokenCache

```cs
public async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
{
    // Use MSAL to swap the code for an access token
    // Extract the code from the response notification
    var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
    string signedInUserID = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

    TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, context.HttpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();
    ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(_azureOptions.ClientId, _azureOptions.Authority, _azureOptions.RedirectUri, new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientCredential(_azureOptions.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, _azureOptions.ApiScopes.Split(' '));
        context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO: Handle
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re not passing the scope in your request.  Can you share some with how you are making the request?

Comment: The first answer you post should be correct. That uses code grant flow to exchange the code for a token. The second blog you post should be for AAD, not AAD B2C and it uses implicit flow and its response type should be `id_token token` , doesn't contains `code`.

Comment: I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926661/6569899) post. Adding 'code' triggered OnAuthorizationCodeReceived where the tokens are added to the cache. This might be the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is you request "token" (=access_token), but don't define scope you want the "token" from. You need to publish the API scope(s), as well as grant permission to the scope(s) in **Azure B2C** portal for the calling application.

Then when logging into the calling application (usually UI app), you can request "token" (access_token) at the time of login by defining the scope you're interested in. If you're properly assigned permission for the calling UI app to the published API app via scopes, you will see the matching scopes in "scp" claim.

Comment: This needs to be done even if there's just one, **single** app registration (e.g. a native client). Just add a _default_ scope, and then give the app permission to this scope - don't forget to grant permissions if needed (for admin type of consent).